# AutoHotkey: Could not close the previous instance of this script. Keep waiting?

Tags: autohotkey

I've got an AutoHotkey script that presents the following error when I try to run it again:

```
Could not close the previous instance of this script. Keep waiting?
```

It's a pretty simple script, with the following settings:

```
#NoEnv
#SingleInstance force
SendMode Input
DetectHiddenWindows, on
SetWinDelay, -1
```

I'm launching the script from the command line. I've tried using the `/f` / `/force` option and there is no effect.

I want the `#SingleInstance Force` behaviour described in the docs, which is described as:

> Skips the dialog box and replaces the old instance automatically, which is similar in effect to the Reload command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out the problem was the `SetWinDelay` instruction.

From the docs:

> Although a delay of -1 (no delay at all) is allowed, it is recommended that at least 0 be used, to increase confidence that the script will run correctly even when the CPU is under load.
>
> A delay of 0 internally executes a Sleep(0), which yields the remainder of the script's timeslice to any other process that may need it. If there is none, Sleep(0) will not sleep at all.

When I had it set to `-1` the script never had time to process other commands, including whatever exit command was sent to it.

Ensure `SetWinDelay` is greater than or equal to 0.